# Entry and exit from different Schengen countries

Tags: visas, schengen

I came to Netherlands from Dubai on a business visa. Now I wish to travel to Paris by train and after two days wish to leave to Dubai direct from Paris. Am I allowed to exit Paris to Dubai when the entry stamp in my passport is Amsterdam?

Comment: short answer - yes

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**.   Schengen visas are valid for entry to and exit from anywhere in the Schengen region.