# Entering Schengen from one country and exiting TO a different country

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, us-residents

I am US resident and Indian citizen (on US student visa), who is currently in Zambia for 2 months. I am planning to visit Europe before I go back to the US. I am applying for the Schengen visa in Zambia to visit Europe (Germany, Italy, France).

Is it possible for me exit Schengen to US, but not to Zambia, who actually granted my visa?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entry and exit from different Schengen countries](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31417/entry-and-exit-from-different-schengen-countries)

Comment: @Karlson, Not a dupe because the OP is referring to leaving to the US instead of returning to Zambia and his question is if its OK to go to the US instead of Zambia after the Schengen Visa is used up considering the fact that he obtained the Visa while he was in Zambia.

Answer (score 3):

You can exit to wherever you want. It's perfectly possible to enter from a third country to a given Schengen country and leave from another Schengen country to yet another third country. No matter where you go or where you exit, you should get an exit stamp, documenting the time you spent in the Schengen area.

Incidentally, Zambia cannot grant you a Schengen visa, only (the consulate of) a Schengen member state can. In principle, you have to be a resident in the relevant area to apply to a given consulate. Hopefully your status in Zambia won't be an issue but that's probably more of a problem than leaving to the US.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. By 'Zambia' I meant 'an embassy in Zambia'.

Comment: The reason I am a little worried about is that the german embassy in Zambia wants to make sure I would come back to Zambia (My residence/visa is valid for at least a month after me exiting Schengen).

But probably there is no way they can make sure I actually entered Zambia after my exit. I am just concerned if the immigration officer while exiting Schengen might ask "Why are you going to the US, when your visa was issued by Zambia consulate. Didn't they want you to come back?"

Comment: @xyz That's because they are used to deal with Zambian residents who would typically come back there. Do submit some proof of your intent to go to the US and a copy of your US visa if you can.

Comment: not really because they are used to handling zambian residents, but they just want to restrict short time stayers like me to use their embassies (because it is easier to get a visa, or for any other reason)